# Replace star ratings in Woocommerce using hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, rating

when enabled, every woocommerce product has a star rating. I have some custom code that I would like to replace the current star rating in its entirety (Including the "# customer reviews" part.

Currently, the code I am using only appends to the star rating, rather than replace it fully. Below is the current result I am seeing, and the code I have added to functions.php. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_star_rating_html', 'replace_star_ratings' );

function replace_star_ratings( $variable ) {
    echo "XXX";
    return $variable;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace completely Stars rating on products without editing templates, use the following:

```
// For single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_rating_single_product_summary', 4 );
function custom_rating_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_rating_count() > 0 ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_product_rating', 9 );
    }

}

// For Shop and archicves pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_rating_after_shop_loop_item_title', 4 );
function custom_rating_after_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_rating_count() > 0 ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'replace_product_rating', 5 );
    }

}

// Content function
function replace_product_rating() {
    global $product;

    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
    $review_count = $product->get_review_count();
    $average      = $product->get_average_rating();

    echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">'. __("XXX", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a ton! You absolutely rock!

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_product_get_rating_html` would be the filter you want, but I don't think even that is broad enough for what you're looking to do.  You're going to have to override the rating.php templates to get all of that changed.

`woocommerce/single-product/rating.php`
if you're doing it on the single product page. if you're doing it in the loop then above filter should work fine, but here's the template location for that anyways
`woocommerce/loop/rating.php`

Comment: That helped a lot! I went to `woocommerce/templates/single-product/rating.php` and  edited the code there. worked exactly as I wanted it to. thanks!

Comment: @BrianDuncan  You don't want to edit the code in place.  You should copy that file into your theme with folder structure the same as the path above (minus the `templates` folder) and put your edited version there.  that way when WooCommerce updates you won't lose all of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

To replace it fully, you'll need to return the HTML code you want to display on the web page.

For instance, I wanted to replace the string "Rated %s out of 5" with Font Awesome stars:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_star_rating_html', 'replace_star_ratings', 10, 2);
function replace_star_ratings($html, $rating) {
    $html = ""; // Erase default HTML
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $html .= $i < $rating ? '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

No need to use `echo` here.